# multiple bundler requirements - unsure what it means

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I saw this:

`gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.6'`

and does it mean greater than 5.0 and less than 5.1 but greater than 5.0.6? This was proposed as a solution to preventing some error messages and not sure if this is a a reasonable idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
'~> 5.0`
```

means a version greater than or equal to 5.0, but less than 5.1. The

```
'>= 5.0.6'
```

means the version must be greater than or equal to version 5.0.6.

Combining the two simply means that

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.6'
```

has to be greater than or equal to version 5.0.6 and less than version 5.1

For more reading check out the [bundler site](http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html)